# Ubuntu 15.10 not installable due missing characters

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, graphics

I wanted to install Ubuntu 15.10, unfortunately something fails. I'm not completly new to linux, but I never had issues installing it.
When I start the installation process it looks like these pictures.

[image] [image]

When trying the live mode, it's sometimes not even starting.
Used Hardware:

- graphics: NVIDIA GTX 750ti oc
- mainboard: MSI h87i ac
- ssd: samsung 840 evo 500gb
- and a usb stick

Windows runs like a charm, Ubuntu 14.04 also runs, but unfortunately my graphics card isn't supported for gaming.

I tried to run the setup, but ignoring this issue. But at the end the setup fails and i get a black screen when trying to boot ubuntu.

Any Ideas how to solve this issue? I couldn't find any solution which helped me. All solutions require that Ubuntu is already installed.

Comment: " unfortunately my graphics card isn't supported for gaming" What ? GTX 750ti oc not supported ? Of course it is `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352`, I have a 650 and it works fine with this driver.

Comment: on ubuntu 14.04? I couldn't find a solution, but if that works, I should stick back to 14.04 :-)

Comment: Yep, 14.04.3 to be exact, you can also look in the `additional drivers` app in the dash to see all available drivers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create the Ubuntu installation media properly with Disks in Ubuntu.
Open **Disks** - select **Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right.
Choose the **ISO file** and the **USB drive** to write it to and **start restoring**.
Alternatively you can burn the Ubuntu 15.10 ISO image to a DVD as well.

Boot from the Ubuntu 15.10 installation media you created before.
Highlight **Try Ubuntu without installing** and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the **end of the linux line**.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Live desktop.

After the installation of Ubuntu 15.10 is finished reboot your computer.
Now install the latest official NVIDIA drivers supporting the GTX 750 Ti.

Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the **end of the linux line**.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot the Ubuntu installation.

When the login screen appears, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

Comment: `nvidia-358` ? Is that a typo ? It is not in my drivers list, latest is 352.63.

Comment: @markkirby : No it's not a typo - nvidia-358 is the latest official one available in the graphics-drivers PPA. :)

Comment: Nice, I did not even know about this :) +1 for that.

Comment: @markkirby : Thank you ! I am using nvidia-358 since it was released -> http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/proprietary-gpu-drivers-ppa/2209 ... and it's working great without any issues. :)

Comment: Just installed myself and it is working great here too :) Thanks.

Comment: Man, trank you, that works Great!

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform a CheckSum on iso just to be sure it is not corrupted.

Edit: since the request, the CheckSum procedure is well documented here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

the procedure may be sum up as:

find the hashcode for your distro (usually here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes or where you downloaded the iso, it is a file called MD5SUMS)

open a terminal, go in the directory where the downloaded iso is and then type:

md5sum [name of the iso file]

the output should be similar to this:

8044d756b7f00b695ab8dce07dce43e5 ubuntu-11.10-dvd-i386.iso

now just compare this hash w.r.t. the one in MD5SUMS

Comment: ece816e12f97018fa3d4974b5fd27337 perfect match :-)

Comment: I had a "similar" problem with Fedora (the live CD or graphical installation constantly failed to install or even boot). I've solved using the netinstall iso. You may give it a try :)

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

Comment: I'll give it a try, if that won't work I'll give the idea of mark kirby a try. :-)

Comment: unfortunately this image doesn't recognize my windows and doesn't start with uefi. So, I'll go back to ubuntu 14.04 LTS :-)

Comment: @MatteoS. For other users stumbling onto this question that don't know how to perform a check-sum, could you [edit] and expand your answer a bit?  Thank you!