# Is DisplayPort 1.2 properly supported in 16.04?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, intel-nuc

About a year ago I tried bringing up (at the time) 15.04 on an i7 NUC (last year's version of http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-kit-nuc5i7ryh.html) with three daisy-chained Dell 2410 monitors, and failed miserably. I ended up using Windows 7 :(

The problem, as I recall, was that the nvidia drivers were failing and taking the kernel with them.

Is anyone running such a configuration successfully?

Thanks!

Comment: I had to deactivate the NVIDIA card during installation in BIOS, then install the proprietary NVIDIA drivers and reenable the NVIDIA card in BIOS: see this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/755667/538840)

Comment: sorry about the tag -- I hadn't noticed that intel-nuc existed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a similar setup, but would urge You to try again. Proprietary nvidia drivers are released quite regularly, so there is a good chance that the Your original issue may have been fixed by now.

[Link to most recently released nvidia driver](http://www.geforce.co.uk/drivers/results/104314)

If simply using the "Try Ubuntu" option on a Live CD/USB does not work (using the bundled open source nouveau driver), then I would try to install Ubuntu on a separate disk first, in order to preserve Your Windows installation.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't have the NUC I mentioned; that was at a previous job, and I'm debating whether to get another NUC (which I absolutely loved, even if it was running Windows) or a more traditional desktop.